# C# Working with a LinkedList DataStructure from base

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I'm currently learning Cambridge Book of dataStructures and each time I think about a problem, before I see the solution, I'm trying to solve it.
I'm Having a problem with  `RemoveLast()`

```
public void RemoveLast()
        {
            if (end != null)
            {
                Node runner = start; //if end != null then start is initialized.
                while (runner != end)
                {
                    runner = runner.Next;
                }
                runner.Next = null;
                end = runner;
             }
        }
```

What is the problem in my code? Thx guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the loop condition:

```
while (runner != end)
```

At the end of the loop, `runner` is equal to `end`. So you are basically setting `end.Next` to `null` and setting `end` to itself.

You need to get to the node right before the `end` node.

Change the loop condition to this:

```
while (runner.Next != end)
```

This will make sure that at the end of the loop, `runner` will be the node exactly before the `end` node.

Please note also that this code does not handle the case where `start` is equal to `end` (when the linked list contains exactly one node).